# How to save a file from a URL with Java

Tags: java, image

I'm have a list of [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), and I need to save files from them to my local folder.

All URLs are links to images, one image per URL. Do I need to read data from the URL or is there any sort of library where I can just specify the URL and file name (of course, get an image extension before) and save it?

Comment: This *may* help, but I'm not sure: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the example *[URL file Download and Save in the Local Directory](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/file-url-download.shtml)*.

Answer (score 3):

Being a Linux administrator, the first thing that comes to mind is possibly using a [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) list function. From Java you could call something like:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" wget -i list_of_images.txt");
```

With the `.txt` file containing the list of all the images, you could export the images to a temporary list. This is a rough method to do it, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Get an InputStream via [URL#openStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) and write it to a File (e.g. via [FileWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)) to your desired location.